# Z-axis issue with the floating review info panel, permits various elements to flow over it

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, information-display, review-history

I was having a look at an old question of mine when I browsed the [reopen review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/70174) from the timeline.

I scrolled downwards and realized the **Review completed** panel comes along for the ride. While that might be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), tags flowing over top of it as pictured below probably isn't.

[image]

Here's a .gif of the **Question** and **Duplicate** tabs flowing over it as well. Note that the timeline button also flows over. If vote buttons are present, they will also flow over it.

[image]

Reproduced on Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

### Update

Per [this now-closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344872/scroll-too-much-and-you-wont-be-able-to-click-the-blue-buttons) by Tiago Martins Peres, this issue also happens in other Review types, namely Late Answers, First Posts and Low Quality Posts. In addition to that, it is causing the action buttons on reviews to become unclickable if you scroll low enough.

[image]

As a temporary workaround, you can use [Samuel Liew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew)'s [ReviewQueueHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js), which [fixes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394159/z-index-issue-in-review-first-post#comment758786_394159) this issue.

Comment: Bug report on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394159

Comment: Also reproducible on Firefox Nightly 75.0a1.

Comment: I got what looks like the same bug reviewing on DBA: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/z-index-problem-while-reviewing

Comment: If interested, I solved it by adding `.js-review-bar { z-index: 999; }` to the CSS I use for my personal adjustments. There's probably a number which is more "appropriate" within the `z-index` values which SE uses, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has [been fixed,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394877/11171084) and is also a very old bug, it appears.

[image]

Loads better. All other elements that previously would flow over will now correctly fall behind this panel.

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue. In particular I keep coming across the problem where quotes go over the top of the buttons making them unclickable.

[image: screenshot of the issue]