# Scroll too much and you won't be able to click the blue buttons

Tags: bug, review, design

Using Chrome on my Windows 10 machine.

This behavior was noticed while reviewing Latest Answers, First Posts, Low Quality Posts.

Tested this in two communities (Stack Overflow and PM Stack Exchange*).

Scrolling to the bottom of the page results in not being able to click any of the blue buttons.

[image: Stack Overflow review after scroll]

[image: PM Stack Exchange review after scroll]

I think that's a bug, but I might be wrong.

*In PM Stack Exchange i couldn't test LQP.