# Indicator about new contributor overlaps action panel in the queue

Tags: bug, review, new-contributor-indicator

> [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tags, tabs, and the timeline button flow over review info panels when scrolling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344041/tags-tabs-and-the-timeline-button-flow-over-review-info-panels-when-scrolling) (presumably the same underlying bug for all these review queue overlap things)

Comment: @Randal'Thor yeap, probably the same issue)