# Accept tickmark and Timeline icons are displayed in wrong Z-order on Review pages

Tags: bug, review, design, accepted-answer, timeline

Being on Review queue pages you can scroll the page while review block itself remains on the top of the page. In such situation some items from the reviewing post (e.g. accepted tickmark or timeline icon) are showed over review block. See animated gif below for clarification:

> [image: accepted tickmark]

I'm using FF 73.0.1 on Windows 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tags, tabs, and the timeline button flow over review info panels when scrolling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344041/tags-tabs-and-the-timeline-button-flow-over-review-info-panels-when-scrolling)