# Close vote review header not alway top element

Tags: bug

I was just going through the close vote review queue and noticed that when I scroll down through the post, there are some elements that cover up the review bar as I go. Notable things appearing above the bar include

Tabs on posts flagged as dupes
[image: Tabs covering the review bar]

Quote blocks

[image: Quote block covering review bar]

Other items behaving this way are question tags, and the post timeline icon. Additionally, quote blocks and tabs being hovered appear to have no background, so the test of the review bar jumbles on top of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tags, tabs, and the timeline button flow over review info panels when scrolling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344041/tags-tabs-and-the-timeline-button-flow-over-review-info-panels-when-scrolling)

Comment: To the reopen reviewers: This question is closed as a duplicate but its duplicate list is empty. This appears to be a bug and is [being discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty).