# Why do some questions closed as duplicates lack a duplicate target?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, meta, community-user

The question https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345815/336163 (asked less than ten minutes ago) was closed as a duplicate less than five minutes ago, but it lacks any semblance of a duplicate target.

The header shows:

> **This question already exists:**

The expected link to the duplicate target is missing.

Its timeline shows that it was closed by "Jenayah, Community♦" as "Duplicate of… " That's it, duplicate of....

What happened, and can we fix it?

I suspected that the duplicate target might simply have been deleted, but then I recognized the extremely short time between closure and now (not really enough time for others to get around to deleting), and also that one generally *can't* vote to delete a question that is a duplicate target - one instead gets a message that the question can't be deleted.

Another example of this happening: [How can I reliably determine if a file is an image file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577469/how-can-i-reliably-determine-if-a-file-is-an-image-file)

Comment: It's still linked on the side list btw.

Comment: @Jenayah Relevant to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty#comment1157036_345289): did you manually delete your automatic closure comment, or was it deleted automatically as per usual?

Comment: This is now an example of a question which **itself demonstrates the bug it's reporting** :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor deleted automatically

Comment: @Randal'Thor and on Meta no less.

Comment: IIRC, for really old questions closed as a duplicate before they implemented the current system at some point, this is how they ended up being displayed in the current system due to some differences in how the old duplicate system was implemented. But in this case, it's happening to new questions...

Comment: @pkamb this is so meta...

Comment: @V2Blast This is not the case for any of these example cases cited here. Both this very question and the one linked here are closed with reason 101, while the old way to close duplicates used reason 1.

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345289/282094