# Deleting comments and review actions cause layout to be broken, AJAX response contains full page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface, moderator-tools

When deleting a comment, the page layout goes haywire, making it impossible to continue working on the page until it is reloaded. It appears something is going b0rken when the 'deleted' state is swapped in.

I can reproduce this on both Chrome (80.0.3987.149) and on Firefox (74.0), on Mac OS X. I disabled all all browser extensions to ensure this was not caused by something I installed locally.

The same effects can also be observed when reviewing in the review queues, where review items result in nested page Chrome.

### Comment deleting example

This is the page before deleting a comment (comments blurred to focus on the layout, not content):

> [image: section of a Stack Overflow page with 4 comments (text blurred) below a question, with sidebar visible to the right, showing the *Related* links and the bottom of the *Featured* box]

After deleting the top comment, where the comments were layd out before, we now have just the deleted comment:

> [image: Same portion of a page as before, but now all but the top comments are gone. The top comment, with pink *deleted* background, now stretches off to the right underneath the sidebar, with the *Related* sidebar header gone and the links shifted downward]

The sidebar on the right has been partially re-arranged. The other comments have mostly disappeared, *except* for their icons and vote counts, and now take up more space, below:

> [image: vestiges of comments, only icons, numbers and a faint shadow]

and if I scroll to the right, those comments are scrunched up on the right-hand side below.. *is that an extra page footer*?!

> [image: footer section scrunched up against the side with comment text below it]

Before anyone asks: no, you can't delete those comments on the right now, as we now have double-loaded JavaScript structures. I can't make it recurse. :-P

Trying to diagnose this, I notice that the comment is being replaced by something that has a `<title></title>` element followed by a whole load more tags I'd expect to find in the *head* of a HTML page.

So I looked at the AJAX response, and it indeed contains a full document:

```
{"Success":true,"Warning":false,"NewScore":-1,"Message":"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n\r\n\r\n    <html class=\"html__responsive html__unpinned-leftnav\">\r\n\r\n    <head>\r\n\r\n        <title></title>\r\n        <link [ ... long document elided ... ]    </body>\r\n    </html>\r\n","Refresh":false,"Transient":false,"Info":false}
```

### Review issues

This also happens when reviewing; review items are loaded over AJAX *with full page chrome*:

> [image: First post review page with doubled header, with some hand-drawn red circles and arrows (ugly) to emphasise the obvious]

Skipping a review post simply results in a JavaScript error (`TypeError: $(...).html(...).addSpinner is not a function`) as the returned response with full HTML page is clearly not working  for whatever is processing the responses.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Possibly related, I wondered if it was just me, but the review queue interactions are buggy at the moment, too. (I get a useless picture-in-picture sort of display)

Comment: Lots of things seem to be broken at the moment. SOCVR scripts have stopped working properly. Review Skip/Done buttons broken in several queues. Layouts gone wonky.

Comment: probably hitting one of our AspNetCore canaries. Can you please report the "lots of other things", too @DavidBuck?

Comment: @m0sa certainly one of those: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394159/z-index-issue-in-review-first-post

Comment: @rene: that's much older, and doesn't match the symptoms seen here. I've not had issues with comments like this before, say, an hour ago. Also, that post has a Meta.SE twin at [Z-axis issue with the floating review info panel, permits various elements to flow over it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344041)

Comment: thanks @rene, not related to this, forwarding it to the right people

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. This kind of stuff is hard to detect when you don't know what you're looking for, we've had the triage queue disabled in our staging environment, additionally this it didn't throw any errors, so it wasn't visible in the logs.

We've reproduced the issue in our staging environment and pushed a fix, so the next time the canaries land it should be fine.

You're not seeing any issues now because we've spun the canaries down in the meantime.