# Unable to handle comment flags from the admin dashboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

While handling comments, the admin dashboard bugs out with the following error in the console:

```
full.en.js?v=38260260cea5:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
at e.submitVote
at e.delete (VM221 moderator.en.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.r (full.en.js?v=38260260cea5:9)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (VM218 jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (VM218 jquery.min.js:3)
```

I am not able to handle any comment flag apart from the first one.

[image]

(This [status-complete]d post seems to be related [Deleting comments and review actions cause layout to be broken, AJAX response contains full page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345598/deleting-comments-and-review-actions-cause-layout-to-be-broken-ajax-response-co))

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - we're digging now.

Comment: We see the issue, fix coming out shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this was just deployed.